# Composite Pattern Simplified

Tags: c#, composite

What do I lose by not implementing the Component and treating everything as a Composite?

I have given up the implementation for Leaf node:

I.e.

```
class Component : IComponent
{ 
    /*...*/ 
}
```

Now plz take a look at my code.

```
public interface IComponent
{
    int ID { get;set; }
    string Name { get;set;}
    void Add(IComponent item);
    void Remove(IComponent item);
    List<IComponent> Items { get; }
    void Show();        
}


public class Composite : IComponent
{
    private int _id;
    public int ID
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public Composite(int id, string name)
    {
        _id = id;
        _name = name;
    }

    private List<IComponent> _items = new List<IComponent>();

    public void Add(IComponent item)
    {
        _items.Add(item);
    }

    public void Remove(IComponent item)
    {
        _items.Remove(item);
    }

    public List<IComponent> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<IComponent>(_items);
        }
    }

    public void Show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ID=" + _id + "; Name=" + _name);
    }        
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IComponent root = new Composite(1, "World");

        IComponent asia = new Composite(2, "Asia");
        IComponent europe = new Composite(3, "Europe");

        root.Add(asia);
        root.Add(europe);

        asia.Add(new Composite(4, "China"));
        asia.Add(new Composite(5, "Japan"));

        europe.Add(new Composite(6, "Germany"));
        europe.Add(new Composite(7, "Russia"));

        root.Show();
        Program.Traverse(root.Items);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void Traverse(List<IComponent> items)
    {            
        foreach (IComponent c in items)
        {
            c.Show();

            Traverse(c.Items);
        }
    }
}
```

What is wrong with this approach of Composite Pattern? What kind of problem can I face with this type of design?

Comment: You might consider clarifying that your question is "what do I lose by not implementing the Component and treating everything as a Composite"... I initially thought you had a problem with the code, and realized that your question is not about the code, which "works", but why you should add the Leaf :)

Comment: Suggest you study the code sample and content here : http://www.dofactory.com/patterns/patterncomposite.aspx Don't see any reason why you should have "given up the implementation for Leaf node." good luck !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're giving up any chance to subclass the "Leaf", if it turns out you have different types of "nodes" you'll probably end up polluting the structure in one way or another. And you're violating the single responsipbility priciple too. It is *very* easy to get pollution of all sorts with the composite pattern, and I think it always pays off to do it cleanly.

Comment: What do you mean by 'pollution'? Can you make a little clear?

Comment: To me it looks like you're not separating tree structure from tree data. Composite is a quite dangerous design pattern because it has a tendency to lure you to put everything into the tree and the nodes, even quite a lot of things that shouldn't be there. Its nice & elegeant, but can also get messy if you put too many different kinds of logic/information into the same view. The "pollution" occurs every time you add a specical case to the tree.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>If I understand correctly, there is ***not*** a concept of leaf node, in composite pattern.</strike>

Any node which doesn't have a child is automatically a leaf node.
Looking at your code, this is not needed

```
private List<IComponent> _items = new List<IComponent>();

    public void Add(IComponent item)
    {
        _items.Add(item);
    }

    public void Remove(IComponent item)
    {
        _items.Remove(item);
    }

    public List<IComponent> Items
    {
        get
        {
                return new List<IComponent>(_items);
        }
    }
```

I am looking at [`ControlCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.controlcollection.aspx) class, which is a property of [`Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.controls.aspx) class.

Though not exactly composite pattern, every Control knows of who it is child of, which is missing from your code.

My understanding could be totally off. Experts can correct me :)

EDIT: I looked at the dofactory reference, which seems to have a concept of leaf class in composite pattern. My mistake of totally not understanding it.

But I would suggest you look at the way .net implements ***kind of*** composite pattern by having `Control`, `ControlCollection` & related classes.

EDIT2: If the code above is to be removed, you will have another class which is a collection of `IComponent` which you can expose by using a property `IList<IComponent>`, which in turn will have methods to `add`/`remove`.

EDIT3: .net doesn't restrict the user from adding child controls in the above class hierarchy. You could use the dofactory way of design, if you want to restrict the ability for someone to define a leaf node (one that doesn't have any child node).

EDIT4: The way dofactory code shows, you will have to define a leaf node, which will throw `NotImplementedException` for `Add`/`Remove'.

Comment: If I give up this code-section, how would I store children? What should be the mechanism then?

Comment: OK. Then what would happen to IComponent-interface? The implementation would not be meaningful anymore. This in turn makes the whole design meaningless.